# Actionbarsherlock noClassDefFoundError com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am migrating my code to use Actionbarsherlock.  I have made all the code adaption that I need to and my project compiles fine with no errors, however I get the following exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$Styleable
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionbarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionbarSherlockCompat.java 1002)

I am using version 4.1 of actionbar sherlock.  I get this exception when the first activity starts every time.  I have cleaned and rebuild the project, checked my buildpaths, and can not find what is missing.  Anyhelp would be great!!!

Comment: Did you do everything listed here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html ?

Comment: @babatenor  actually I have not, and that is probably the issue.  I had built the ABS lib and placed the jar in my project.  Now I am adding the library to my project as suggested in the usage section of the site.  Now I am getting a GC overhead exceeded error when compiling.  I will update when I this eclipse error fixed.

Comment: @babatenor I have got this working now by adding it as a library.  Thanks for the tip.  If you write an answer I will accept it...@Jake Wharton thanks for the awesome lib!

Comment: Glad it helped. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using the Eclipse Development Environment with the ADT plugin version 0.9.7 or greater you can include `ActionBarSherlock` as a library project. Create a new Android project in Eclipse using the library/ folder as the existing source. Then, in your project properties, add the created project under the ‘Libraries’ section of the ‘Android’ category.

The rest of the user manual is [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html).

Answer (score 11):

I got this Error to when using the SDK Tools **Preview 21** and the ADT preview.

Occurred when inflating menu items with actionbarsherlock using. `getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);`

Reverting to SDK Tools 20 fixed it.

logcat error:

```
11-03 09:29:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(14878): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
11-03 09:29:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(14878):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:343)
11-03 09:29:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(14878):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:162)
11-03 09:29:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(14878):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
```

Comment: Good find! I can confirm this. Would be interesting to know what exactly is causing the problem...

Comment: I can confirm, related to r21

Comment: Just updated to SDK Tools 21.0.1 and appears to have fixed this problem!

Comment: The problem is also happening with release r21.1. I fixed it by downgrading to r21 / adt R21.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. updating to the latest version of actionbarsherlock and doing a clean all helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may caused by ADT version,I solved this issue by using adt-bundle-windows-x86.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after signing the application. The signed apk was returning the above error, while before signing everything worked well. Closing that damn eclipse and starting it again (built in restart option did not work) did the trick for me.