# NoClassDefFoundError ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android-layout, actionbarsherlock, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting reports of my new app crashing from some users.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$layout
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1039)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:919)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:218)
at com.androidProjects.personal.GAAClubFinderActivity.onCreate(GAAClubFinderActivity.java:58)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea what could be causing this because the same version is working fine on my own phone using Android 4.0.4.

Is there some issues with ABS and older version of the Android OS?

I have decalred my min and target versions as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424723/actionbarsherlock-noclassdeffounderror-com-actionbarsherlock-rstyleable.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar does not exist for old Android SDK versions. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Therefore you can't run your app in the Android lover then 3.0 when you use ActionBar.

MinSdk version doesn't check usages in the compile time because you can programmatically create if/switch and call different code for different platforms.